# FFMPEG Waveform with specific color

Tags: ffmpeg

looking to get a waveform from an input that is this specific gold color #ad9557 (173/255, 149/255, 87/255) and have a transparent background / or black if not possible.

I'm currently using this script to generate it:

```
command = new String[]{
                "-i", mRapFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                "-filter_complex",
                "showwavespic",
                "-frames:v",
                "1",
                mWaveFormFile.getAbsolutePath()};
```

The waveform is there but is a weird orange color now. How can I change this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Use the `colors` option in [showwavespic](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwavespic) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwavespic=colors=#ad9557" -frames:v 1 output.png
```

I had to make some assumptions because you did not include the complete console output from your command:

- Your `ffmpeg` may be too old for the `colors` option. See [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to up-to-date already compiled binaries for Linux, OS X, and Windows.
- I don't know the channel layout of your input(s). I added [aformat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aformat-1) to make mono audio: otherwise all of the channels would be different colors and you would have to specify the color for each. Default is `red|green|blue|yellow|orange|lime|pink|magenta|brown`